# form wont send after button click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I used dreamweavers auto fill to get the php log in and register stuff but when i hit the button nothing happens... Ive tried putting the button inside and outside of the form, ive watched many tutorials and they all do the same thing.

```
    <?php require_once('../Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

// *** Redirect if username exists
$MM_flag="MM_insert";
if (isset($_POST[$MM_flag])) {
  $MM_dupKeyRedirect="index.php";
  $loginUsername = $_POST['Username'];
  $LoginRS__query = sprintf("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Username=%s", GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"));
  mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
  $LoginRS=mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);

  //if there is a row in the database, the username was found - can not add the requested username
  if($loginFoundUser){
    $MM_qsChar = "?";
    //append the username to the redirect page
    if (substr_count($MM_dupKeyRedirect,"?") >=1) $MM_qsChar = "&";
    $MM_dupKeyRedirect = $MM_dupKeyRedirect . $MM_qsChar ."requsername=".$loginUsername;
    header ("Location: $MM_dupKeyRedirect");
    exit;
  }
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "registerForm")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (Fname, Lname, Username, Password, Email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Fname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Lname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Username'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['password'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_Register = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Register = mysql_query($query_Register, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Register = mysql_fetch_assoc($Register);
$totalRows_Register = mysql_num_rows($Register);
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['user'];
  $password=$_POST['pwd'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "members/lobby.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "index.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = true;
  mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT Username, Password FROM users WHERE Username=%s AND Password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && true) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Yeti Draft</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>


  <body>
    <div id = "container">
    <div id = "navbar">
        <nav>
            <ul>

              <div id = navStart>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Winners!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li></div>
                <div id = "login"><li><a href="#loginModal" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>
                <li class = "sign"><a href="#registerModal" data-toggle="modal">Sign Up</a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id = "content">
    </div>
    <div id = "footer">
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- Login modal -->    
        <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class = "modal-dialog">
                    <div class = "modal-content">
                        <div class = "modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h3 class="modal-title">Login</h3> 
                        </div>    
                        <div class="modal-body">
                      <form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" METHOD="POST" id="loginForm">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="username">Username</label>
                                <input type="Username" class="form-control" id="user">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                                </div>
                                </form>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer"> 
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>   

                    </div>        
                </div>
  </div> 
        </div>

    <!-- Register modal -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class = "modal-dialog">
                <div class = "modal-content">
                    <div class = "modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h3> 
                    </div>    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="registerForm" id="registerForm">
                            <h4>First Name: <br> 
                                      <input name="Fname" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="Fname">
                    </h4>
                                    <h4>Last Name: <br> 
                                      <input name="Lname" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="Lname">
                                    </h4>
                                    <h4>Username:<br><input name="Username" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="Username">
                                    </h4>
                                    <h4>Email: <br><input name="email" type="email" required="required" class="form-control" id="email">
                                    </h4>
                                    <h4>Password:<br><input name="password" type="password" required="required" class="form-control" id="password">
                                    </h4>
                                     <h4>Confirm Password:<br><input type="password" required="required" class="form-control">
                                    </h4>
                                     <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="registerForm">   
                                    </form>                     
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="signup">Sign Up</button>
                  </div>        
            </div>
        </div> 


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Register);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of your `button`:

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" name="signup">Sign Up</button>`

Setting `type="button"` prevents form from sending.

Comment: ok i got that to work but the login part still doesnt send you anywhere when the login is succesful.

Comment: You asked about form not sending, not missing redirect. Either rewrite your question or ask a new one.